# application layer protocol for propagation between nodes

Tags: transaction-propagation, websockets, http

for the propagation process between nodes in the networks, witch application layer protocol they use, HTTP or WebSocket?

And if they use WebSocket, does each node maintain a continuous connection with each of the other nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Used Bitcoin protocol over TCP/IP protocol. 
You can read more on this link https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Message_types

Comment: the OP is asking about application level, not infrastructure / TCP/IP layer. Probably a link to the code would help more, to understand how listeners are opened for incoming messages?

Comment: Nodes not use HTTP or WebSocket protocol. Nodes connect over TCP/IP and start handshake https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Version_Handshake